# What is the meaning of this reactjs line of code?

Tags: reactjs

Please what is the meaning of these reactjs lines of codes? I mean, in English interpretation?

```
 {
   singleComment.author.username == user?.username &&  <div className="comment-edit-delete-div">
   <i className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => {setUpdateComment(_id); setCommentDescription(commentdescription)}}  ></i>
 <i className="singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt" onClick={() => handleCommentDelete(_id)}  ></i>
```

}

I am confused about how to interpret user?.username. What is the question mark doing there?

Comment: Optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: The use of "?." is there to make a check if the "username" attribute exists.

If in an initial state user is null or undefined, it will return undefined and not an error.

In the end it serves to prevent the error in case "user" is not (yet) an object type.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. Becus I tried singleComment.author.username == user.username.. It worked but threw in error when the username is null. I think your explanation made it clearer now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

This operator is available in node version 14 and above.